# How can I pass the encryption I have in Java (android) that works for me pass it to Swift I have tried several ways and I can not

Tags: ios, swift

You can help me I have an application in android that uses this encryption but in Ios with swift I cannot make it work I have looked for an example and I cannot find.

```
public class Encript {

    private static String IV = "e123f725e675f456";
    private static String PASSWORD = "@atencion03crypt";
    private static String SALT = "S@1tS@1t";
    

    public String encryptAndEncode(String raw) {
        try {
            Cipher c = getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
            byte[] encryptedVal = c.doFinal(getBytes(raw));
            String s = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedVal, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return s;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }


    private String getString(byte[] bytes) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    }

    private byte[] getBytes(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    }

    private Cipher getCipher(int mode) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] iv = getBytes(IV);
        c.init(mode, generateKey(), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return c;
    }

    private Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        char[] password = PASSWORD.toCharArray();
        byte[] salt = getBytes(SALT);
        

        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 128);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        byte[] encoded = tmp.getEncoded();
        return new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of some classes and the implementation of encoding and decoding of these classes still need to be completed, but it should be like this...

```objectivec
import Foundation
let IV = "e123f725e675f456"
let PASSWORD = "@atencion03crypt"
let SALT = "S@1tS@1t"
class SecretKeyFactory: NSObject {
    let key: String?
    init(_ key: String) {
        self.key = key
    }
    
}
func encryptAndEncode(with raw: String) -> String {
    do {
        let s = try Int("2add")
    } catch  {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return "a"
}



private func generateKey() throws {
    let factory = SecretKeyFactory("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")
    let password = Array(PASSWORD)
    var salt: [UInt8]?
    SALT.getBytes(&salt, maxLength: SALT.count, usedLength: salt?.count, encoding: .utf8, range: RangeExpression(), remaining: )
    let spec = PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 128)
    //Factory should also implement the initialization method like secretkeyfactory
    let tmp = factory(spec)
    //SecretKey、SecretKeySpec
    //The coding protocol is used to indicate that the language struct can be encoded and decoded, and then the encode method of jsonencoder class is used to encode.
    //like this
    /*
     import UIKit
     struct Language: Codable {
        var name: String
        var version: Int
        func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
          return ["name": self.name], "version": self.version]
     }
     
     let language = Language(name: "Swift", version: 4)
     let encoder = JSONEncoder()
     let encoded = try? encoder.encode(language)
     let decoder = JSONDecoder()
     let obj = try? decoder.decode(Language.self, )
     
     */
}

extension String {
    //Base64 Encode
    func encodeBase64() -> String? {
        if let data = self.data(using: .utf8) {
            return data.base64EncodedString()
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    //Base64 Decode
    func decodeBase64() -> String? {
        if let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) {
            return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I am testing the code and it gives me this error and I change it but it always marks that error, what happens, I am new to swift, it costs me a bit, I have been doing this for 2 weeks. if you can help me please.

Comment: here I get an error on this line
     SALT.getBytes (& salt, maxLength: SALT.count, usedLength: salt? .Count, encoding: .utf8, range: RangeExpression (), remaining:)